# Plotting a stacked bar graph after grouping data on multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a Pandas dataframe that has 2 columns like -

```
Vendor     Product    Category
VendorA    ProdABC       B
VendorA    ProdXYZ       C
VendorAB   ProdCDC       A
VendorAB   ProdDEF       A
VendorAB   ProdKLM       B
VendorF    ProdXYZ       D
VendorC    ProdBSE       C
VendorF    ProdFGH       D
VendorAB   ProdMNO       D
VendorA    ProdFGH       D
VendorV    ProdCDC       A
VendorF    ProdBSE       C
```

I need to -

1. Find out the top 10 vendors who have the the most number of products listed, and
2. Create a stacked bar graph (matplotlib) depicting the category-wise breakdown of number of products for these top 10 vendors, to show the comparison of total products and categories of products sold by the top 10 vendors.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I will use the dataframe you have shown in your question**

For the first task use [groupby.size](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html)

```
top10=df.groupby('Vendor').size().sort_values(ascending=False).head(10)
print(top10)



Vendor
VendorAB    3
VendorA     2
VendorF     1
dtype: int64
```

---

After create group by `vendors` of **top10** (using: [DataFrame.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)) and `categories` an use [DataFrame.unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to plot with [DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
top10_by_categories=df[df['Vendor'].isin(top10vendors)].groupby(['Vendor','Category']).count()['Product'].unstack()
categories=top10_by_categories.columns
top10_by_categories['total']=top10_by_categories.sum(axis=1)
top10_by_categories.sort_values(by='total',ascending=False,inplace=True)
print(top10_by_categories)
top10_by_categories[categories].plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)





Category    A    B    C    D  total
Vendor                             
VendorAB  2.0  1.0  NaN  NaN    3.0
VendorA   NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN    2.0
VendorF   NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0    1.0
```

[image]

Comment: shouldn't it be `groupby(['Vendor', 'Category'])`? I need the top Vendors on the X-Axis and each vendor's products categorised by different stacked categories.

Comment: Thanks @lostCode!! That works for me. :) How can I get just the category name in the legend, instead of (Product, CategoryName)?

Comment: you only need use `droplevel` to delete Product level, then it disappear of legend. I have updates the code

Comment: Is there a way of displaying the vendors in decreasing order of products (in this case, VendorAB, VendorA, VendorF from left to right) ?

Comment: Also, using this method, I get some categories listed twice both in the `top10_by_categories` dataframe and the the stacked bar chart legend. :(

Comment: i update the code with vendors in decreasing orders

Comment: I don't know why you get duplicated categories. Please update your dataframe of your example. I am trying droop duplicated categories

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200137/discussion-between-lostcode-and-harry04).